# mysqldump restoring a database backup into a empty database using terminal ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, terminal, lamp

steps:

**got bananas database backup:**

```
mysqldump -u root -p bananas > /var/www/site.com/bananas_backup.sql
```

**I created a new empty datase;**

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE bananas2019;
```

**now appplying bananas backup into bananas 2019;**

```
mysqldump -u root -p bananas2019 < bananas_backup.sql
```

**got this:**

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: bananas2019
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2018-11-30 19:16:05
```

I went to check my database and still empty with no data why?

my backup it is in the right directory and has data, already checked this.

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`mysqldump` just dumps data, it's not used for importing. For that you can use `mysql`:

```
mysql -u root -p bananas2019 < bananas_backup.sql
```